# CSS: Copy runtime width

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to apply the runtime width from one element to another element using only CSS and no javascript? If not...CSS4 needs this :).

Comment: Without more information, the answer is: no. With more information, the answer is still probably no.

Comment: What more information do you need? It's a simple question...is there a CSS attribute that mirrors a second element's properties? I know how to do this with javascript, but I thought maybe there was an advanced CSS hack I've never used.

Comment: Like I said, the *general answer* is no. If you would have described your situation *in detail*, there may have been a way to do it for your specific layout. You didn't do that, so your question was closed as "not a real question".

Comment: Right...I don't need to explain a situation. I know how to do this programatically. I just wondered if the CSS 3 spec had something I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, this is not possible with css only, unless elements are wrapped one inside another.

Answer (score 3):

Other then when you are talking about [shrink wrapping](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css%20shrinkwrapping#hl=en&sa=X&ei=1RiNTZ3tOpGahQePlPG7Dg&ved=0CBUQBSgA&q=css%20shrink%20wrapping&spell=1&fp=16d6ef728f346c78) an element with its container, or when you have a block element with `width: auto` expanding to fill its container, this isn't possible.

Comment: Ya, I'm familiar with that idea. Maybe I'll redactor my layout. Thanks